# How To Fix My Kernel Version?

Tags: kernel

I have recently updated my kernel version. I restarted my computer and this is what I get!

[image]

I have installed the version 'Ubuntu, with Linux 3.4.0-030400 version. When I click enter with the first choice. My machine boots to the version but after clicking the new version, my screen stays purple. I restated my machine, went to the grub screen then to the 'Previous Linux Versions', then went back to my previous kernel version 3.2.0-39-generic' and runs correctly and works perfect.

Proof

[image: Previous Kernel Versions]

[image]

How can I delete this new kernel and get the previous one back? Can I restore to an older time, with the good kernel? Can I delete all the kernels and put this new one in?

Comment: Do you want to remove the 3.2.0-40 entry?

Comment: I want the previous version, and get rid of the new one. Yes

Comment: please add the output of the following command `ls -ltr /boot`

Answer (score 2):

My system crashed in the middle of an upgrade and after reboot my kernel was hosed.  Because i'm lazy, I remember boot repair which i've used in the past to fix grub, it has an option to repair the kernel.

Boot from live cd and:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -y boot-repair
boot-repair
```

Answer (score 1):

I would advice you to use Synaptic to uninstall it, unless you're comfortable with using the Terminal. So please install Synaptic:

```
sudo apt-get install synaptic
```

When done, run Synaptic like you would any other app. In it, click on the `Status` button in the lower left part, then select `Installed` in the upper left part of the screen. Search for `linux 3.4`. Delete any packages that have `linux-headers` or `linux-image` in their name and are labeled with version number 3.4*. Restart the computer.

If I may notice, you should also delete any kernels older than the one you're using (3.2.0-40), because there's no need for them, and they can really take up your HDD space. To remove them, you can use the same method as for 3.4* and just changing the version numbers, or you can install Ubuntu Tweak tool and delete them all at once from the `Janitor` tab.

Comment: The solution of my problem was going around the kernel. I used a program called 'Grub Customizer'. The details that you gave me still, was done. But did not work. Thank you for the help.